# webrtc remote video on firefox not work

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc

iam use webrtc for made an video call when i made an call between chrome and chrome work without problem
but when i made call with firefox ... firefox share video to chrome but video from chrome not shown in firefox i think there are problem in attach mediastream for firefox because

> the video element src read this

```
<video id="remoteVideo"  autoplay="" src="[object MediaStream]"></video>
```

and in console of firefox its show this

```
 404 failed to load http://localhost/videocall/[object%20MediaStream].
```

and this is my code for attach stream to video element

```
 pc.onaddstream = function(event) {
  var ts = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
   attachMediaStreamx(ts, event.stream);

};


  attachMediaStreamx = function(element, stream) {
if (typeof element.srcObject !== 'undefined') {
  element.srcObject = stream;
} else if (typeof element.mozSrcObject !== 'undefined') {
  element.mozSrcObject = stream;
} else if (typeof element.src !== 'undefined') {
  element.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
} else {
  console.log('Error attaching stream to element.');
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
pc.onaddstream = function(event) {
  remoteVideo.srcObject = event.stream;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have src="[object MediaStream]" in your HTML code. Just remove that bit. It is probably interfering with the srcObject.